# Extract words with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new with RegEx, but it would be very useful to use it for my project. What I want to do in Javascript is this :

I have this kind of string "/this/is/an/example" and I would like to extract each word of that string, that is to say :

"/this/is/an/example" -> this, is, an, example. And then use each word.

Up to now, I did :

```
var str = "/this/is/a/test"; 
var patt1 = /\/*/g;
var result = str.match(patt1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

and it returns me : /,,,,,/,,,/,,/,,,,,

I know that I will have to use .slice function next if I can identify the position of each "/" by using search for instance but using search it only returns me the index of the first "/" that is to say in this case 0.

I cannot find out.

Any Idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So actually you do not really want to “match words”, but all you want to do is split the given text at the `/` character ... (and how to do that, should be easy enough to research.)

Comment: It looks like you're looking for the `str.split()` method.

Comment: Or, `str.match(/[^\/]+/g)`

Comment: `str.split("/");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `split()`

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

```js
var str = "/this/is/a/test"; 
var array = str.split('/');
console.log(array);
```

In case you want to do with regex.

```js
var str = "/this/is/a/test"; 
var patt1 = /(\w+)/g;
var result = str.match(patt1)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: He's asking about how to do with regex

Comment: @StefansArya: Which in this case is like asking how to drive in a nail with a haddock. Use the right tool for the job. The right tool here is `split`

Comment: @StefansArya Updated the solution, I think splitting would be better approach.

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed, it works with a split(). I forgot this solution while I was trying with RegEx.

Comment: @MattBurland: Actually I know that, but the question was about RegEx. Do you think it's not out of topics if you answer it with split?

Comment: @StefansArya: No - absolutely not. The answers should focus on achieving the ultimate goal of the code and not on one particular solution. What you are describing is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MattBurland: I see.. anyway, when you use split("/") we still need to remove first index because the method was not equal

Answer (score 3):

Well I guess it depends on your definition of 'word', there is a 'word character' match which might be what you want:

```
var patt1 = /(\w+)/g;
```

[Here is a working example of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/EdKD25/1)

Full JS example:

```js
var str = "/this/is/a/test"; 
var patt1 = /(\w+)/g;
var match = str.match(patt1);

var output = match.join(", ");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex: `/\b[^\d\W]+\b/g`, to have a specific word just access the index in the array. e.g `result[0] == this`

```js
var str = "/this/is/a/test";
var patt1 = /\b[^\d\W]+\b/g;
var result = str.match(patt1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: @E.B If you want the regex to recognize numbers, just remove the \d