# Extract words from a string and split

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a question. I have a very long string that also contain special characters. I want to use regex to extract the words and use the split function to get the desired output.

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

I've tried this two different approaches.

```
var fill = "|@!../::one:://::two:://::three:://four:://five|".match("([0-9a-zA-Z_]").split(" ");

var fill = "|@!../::one:://::two:://::three:://four:://five|".toString().split(" "), function(a) { return /[0-9a-zA-Z_]/.test(a)};
```

> .match(...).split is not a function

I'm error message I'm receiving. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you're not using jQuery.

Comment: The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45675176/3832970), `s.match(/\w+/g)`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to get all matches. That can be done via `exec()` method of RegExp:

```
const matchWords = /[a-z0-9_]+/gi;
const results = [];
const testStr = "|@!../::one:://::two:://::three:://four:://five|";
let match = null;
while(match = matchWords.exec(testStr)) {
    results.push(match[0]);
}
console.log(results);
```

To see why and how it works, see MDN docs on [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: It works but it's more simple to use [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).